# pagination is not working with store procedure in yii

Tags: php, yii

I wants to do pagination with Store Procedure yii, when i load page first time it shows me 10 records but when i click on 2nd page it shows me no record found, Here is my code

```
            if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']!='') {
                $page = $_GET['page'];
            } else {
                $page = 1;
            }
            $SP = "CALL Dormantreport(1,'2015-01-01','2015-12-31','',".$page.",10)";
            $command =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand($SP);
            $rawDataWithArray = $command->queryAll();

            $filteredData=$filtersForm->filter($rawDataWithArray);
            $model = new CArrayDataProvider($rawDataWithArray, array( 
                        'keyField' => 'MemberID', 
                        'totalItemCount' => 78, //count($rawDataWithArray),
                        'sort' => array(
                            'attributes' => array(
                                'MemberID',
                            ),
                            'defaultOrder' => array(
                                'MemberID' => CSort::SORT_DESC, 
                            ),
                        ),
                       'pagination' => array(
                            'pageSize' => $PageSize,
                        ),
                    ));
            return $model;
```

Can anyone please tell me what i need to do now to solve this pagination issue, any help will be really appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

In your model,

```
 public function search() {
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->order = 'employeedetailsid DESC';



    $criteria->compare('employeedetailsid', $this->employeedetailsid);
   $criteria->compare('employeemasterid', $this->employeemasterid);
    $criteria->compare('employeedetails_qualification', $this->employeedetails_qualification, true);
    $criteria->compare('employeedetails_experience', $this->employeedetails_experience, true);
    $criteria->compare('employeedetails_address1', $this->employeedetails_address1, true);


    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'pagination' => array(
            'pagesize' => 25,
        )
    ));
}
```

Try this....